# Improve WPF / telerik (Rad)TreeListView bad scrolling performance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, radtreeview

I use a telerik `RadTreeListView` in my .NET 6 WPF application and experience very bad performance during scrolling.

Updates when using the scroll wheel can take 2 seconds and dragging the vertical scroll bar quickly results in lag spikes of <=5 seconds.

I have about 350 rows which are organized under a single top-level element. The view has 5 manually defined columns.

I profiled the performance and saw that virtually all the CPU time spent on the UI thread is used for layouting:

[image: Profiling the problem]

I tried enabling the virtualizing functionality by using the attributes `EnableRowVirtualization`, `EnableColumnGroupsVirtualization`, `EnableColumnVirtualization`.

What steps can I take to improve my scroll performance?

Edit: Here is the XAML of an example project that illustrates my problem.

```xml
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"
                                              BusyContent="{Binding BusyReason}" IsBusy="{Binding BusyReason, Converter={StaticResource stringEmptyConverter}}" >
            <telerik:RadTreeListView  x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoExpandItems="True"
                                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPage}"
                                                 PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="RadTreeListView_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" IsDragDropEnabled="False"
                                      PreparedCellForEdit="treeView_PreparedCellForEdit"
                                      BeginningEdit="treeView_BeginningEdit"
                                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                      EnableColumnGroupsVirtualization="False"
                                      EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
                                      GroupRenderMode="Flat"
                                      IsPropertyChangedAggregationEnabled="False"
                                      >
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                    <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding ChildElements, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name, TargetNullValue=''}" Header="ID Name"
                                                Width="Auto" IsSortable="False" IsFilterable="False"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn  Header="ID" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                IsSortable="False" IsFilterable="False"
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTreeListView}}, Path=DataContext.Ids}"
                                                     Width="100"
                                                    x:Name="columnWarnId"
                                                    IsLightweightModeEnabled="True"
                                                     EmptyText="not set"
                                                    >
                        <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.EditorStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadComboBoxStyle}">
                                <Setter Property="OpenDropDownOnFocus" Value="True"/>
                            </Style>
                        </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.EditorStyle>
                        <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dt:DataObject}">
                                <telerik:Label Content="{Binding IdName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Ca, TargetNullValue=''}" Header="Foobar"
                                                IsFilterable="False" 
                                                Width="65"
                                                x:Name="columnCa"
                                                />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding HasChanged, TargetNullValue=''}" Header="*"
                                                IsFilterable="False"
                                                IsReadOnly="True">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding HasChanged, Converter={helpers:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Text="*"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding WarningsPresent, TargetNullValue=''}" Header="Warning"
                                                IsFilterable="False"
                                                IsReadOnly="True">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding WarningsPresent, Converter={helpers:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"                                    Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/icons8-fehler-48.png"
                                       Stretch="Uniform" 
                                       MaxHeight="24"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadTreeListView>
        </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```

Comment: Can you provide XAML.. which property you are using. What is value of TreeDerivationMode ? Also you can investigate your output window - probably there will be binding errors.

Comment: There were no Binding Errors with this example. I don't know which element should offer a `TreeDerivationMode` property, so I can't verify which value it is set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The telerik Support offered feedback.

The performance problem stems from the `GridViewComboBoxColumn` that - in my case - displays ~200 entries (the same for each row).

It's a [known issue](https://feedback.telerik.com/wpf/1352336-slow-scrolling-when-a-gridviewcomboboxcolumn-is-bound-to-a-large-dataset) that is not considered a bug by telerik since 2015.

The root cause is that the underlying `RadComboBox` evaluates its contents even if it's not extended. When I removed the `GridViewComboBoxColumn` from my `RadTreeView`, performance jumped to acceptable levels in *Debug* mode and good performance in *Release* mode.

The support page linked above suggests rewriting the collection for the ComboBox' items to a dictionary so that telerik-internal performance is improved.